# Hybrid correlation/MSE metric?

Tags: correlation, distance, metric

Apologies as this is probably a rather naive question

I would like to compare two vectors and neither a correlation (e.g pearsons/spearmans) nor a distance metric (eg rmse) is quite right and ideally I want something that encompasses a bit of both.

I want the metric to both account for differences in scale e.g. comparing [0.1, 0.2, 0.3] with another vector should give a better score if that vector is [0.2, 0.3, 0.4] compared to [2,3,4], but also in terms of direction i.e the  score should also be better when comparing that first vector  [0.2, 0.3, 0.6] than  with [0.2, 0.1, 0.0].

Is there any established metric that somehow combines these types of approaches giving some sort of hybrid pearson/rmse measure?

If it is relevant the end goal is to construct a similarity matrix that will then have a clustering analysis performed on it

Comment: I don't get it, this is both solved with correlation, it is scale invariant and can capture both directions?

Comment: Sorry I probably wasnt clear - I don't want it to be scale variant. I guess probably the unstandardised regression coefficient does the job.